# Setting up Symfony with Nginx server

Tags: php, symfony1, nginx

My project requires to set up symfony with Nginx server. I have previously used Symfony with Apache. Currently I have followed the steps mentioned here http://wiki.nginx.org/index.php?title=Symfony&oldid=6054 ,but somehow it is not running properly.

**Update:** The nginx wiki now contains [working configuration for symfony 1.4 and 2.0](http://wiki.nginx.org/Symfony)

Comment: Which symfony version? What *exactly* is not working?

Comment: @hakre - I am using symfony version 1.4.11 (doctrine)

Comment: And about the *"somehow it is not running properly"*, how does this look like? Can you be more specific?

Comment: I guess i am having problem with the htaccess as i am not able to redirect other pages to index.php.

Comment: Can you please send me an example of a configuration file with symfony already set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working [symfony nginx config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3998856/nginx-friendly-php-framework/6750433#6750433).

It is based on Ubuntu/Debian installations, please comment/edit at the linked post if conversion to another platform might be required.

Edit: *The error mentioned in the comments has been fixed in the linked answer.*

Comment: Thanks for the config file link. But its not working,after editing all the required paths.i.e, my symfony project not working.It shows " 404 Not Found " Error.

Comment: @Janmejay: Sorry about that & thanks for testing the config, I have tested it myself now and fixed it. I also ported security related settings from my live system into the config, so I can vouch now that it is fit for production use.

Comment: so from where can i access the fixed file? is it url above which you shared earlier?

Comment: Hi, this lick is broken right now. I'm looking for correct configuration for symfony 1.4

Comment: Hey webdevbyjoss, the link works but here it is again: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3998856/nginx-friendly-php-framework/6750433#6750433