# Symfony2 - Nginx/FPM vs Apache

Tags: apache, symfony, nginx, php

I have a problem with the Symfony cache. When I test the same project (in dev env) with Apache and Nginx PHP-FPM. Apache is 10 times faster. (4900ms vs 500ms)

I have made some "strace" on several processus, and I have seen that with Apache Symfony care about the cache. But with Nginx/FPM, Symfony seems execute all the code. (without use application cache)

What are the differences that could say to symfony to use the correctly cache with Apache and not with Nginx?

Or, are there some special configuration to do with Nginx/FPM in DEV environment ?

Thanks

= NGINX Configuration =

```
location / { 
    index app.php;
    if (-f $request_filename) {
        break;
    }   
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /app.php last;
}
location ~ (app|app_dev).php {
    include /etc/nginx/nginx-fpm.conf;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
}
```

= /etc/nginx/nginx-fpm.conf ==

```
fastcgi_pass   unix:/tmp/php-fpm.sock;
fastcgi_index  index.php;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        80;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
```

== PHP-FPM ==

```
[global]
pid = /var/run/php5-fpm.pid
error_log = /var/log/php5-fpm.log
include=/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/*.conf
```

= /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf =

```
[www]
user = www-data
group = www-data
listen = /tmp/php-fpm.sock
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 10
pm.start_servers = 4
pm.min_spare_servers = 2
pm.max_spare_servers = 6
pm.status_path = /status
access.log = /var/log/fpm/www.access.log
access.format = %R - %u %t "%m %r%Q%q" %s %f %{mili}d %{kilo}M %C%%
chdir = /
```

== APC ==

```
extension=apc.so
apc.shm_segments=1
apc.shm_size=512M
apc.enable_cli=1
apc.include_once_override=1
apc.canonicalize=1
apc.stat="0" ; OR 1 it's the same result
```

== Others extensions ==

```
apc.ini
curl.ini
gd.ini
imagick.ini
intl.ini
memcached.ini
memcache.ini
mysqli.ini
mysql.ini
pdo.ini
pdo_mysql.ini
pdo_sqlite.ini
sqlite3.ini
sqlite.ini
```

Comment: How can anybody answer that question who not has configured a) the symfony dev environment and b) both webservers. My best guessed answer: Take the green pill.

Comment: Having done both a) and b) with only a few problems, I can safely say that there's no "special" configuration that's needed. Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706745/setting-up-symfony-with-nginx-server and the linked [configuration](http://wiki.nginx.org/Symfony)?

Comment: Yes, I've already try a lot of configuration (nginx and php and apc). It's really like if symfony doesn't use his cache. When I clear the cache, with Apache the first request takes 4s and the others take 300ms. With Symfony it's always 5s. Like if Symfony doesn't see the cache.

Comment: You should include your config here to see if there's a problem with it. Have you checked the file permissions to ensure that the cache folder can be written when serving via nginx/FPM?

Comment: I just add my configuration. It's a very basic configuration but we never know... Apache and FPM use the www-data user and group. No problem on the file permission. I even try to delete the app/dev folder. Everything is re-created with Nginx/FPM. The generated cache is fully fonctionnal with Apache. Thx

Comment: You enabled apc for fpm too, or only for apache-module?

Comment: The php.ini is the same for Apache and Nginx/FPM

Comment: Plopix, have you ever gotten this solved?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I didn't have much more time to spent on this problem so I work on Apache in dev mode since this problem. Why this question ? Do you have the same issue ? I believed this issue came from a specific "somethings" on my side, but if you have the same, I could try to reproduce and dive again to find a solution.

Comment: I have the same problem. Symfony runs very slow on a Linux machine with nginx and php-fpm.

Comment: just a stab in the dark here... if you're using Vagrant to test, DO NOT USE virtualbox shared folders. At the very least use NFS. Or even better yet, use rsync.

Comment: just a stab in the dark here... if you're using Vagrant to test, DO NOT USE virtualbox shared folders. At the very least use NFS. Or even better yet, use rsync.