# Setting proper path in Nginx for Symfony2

Tags: symfony, nginx

I need to have my symfony app installed on the same domain as other webapps so I wanted it to sit in /dev/symfony_app path

I tried to use [NginX Friendly PHP Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3998856/nginx-friendly-php-framework/6750433#6750433) but solutions from there do not work.

I have such nginx config and it does not work at all too. there is some problem with paths, nor root neither alias directive work for me.

```
location /dev/symfony_app/ {
    root /home/.../public_html/web;
}
location ~ ^/dev/symfony_app/(app|app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
}
```

nginx error log:

request http://domain.com/dev/symfony_app/

```
2013/06/23 11:25:31 [error] 22549#0: *668 
"/home/.../public_html/web/dev/symfony_app/index.php"
is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: *,
server: domain.com, request: "GET /dev/symfony_app/ HTTP/1.1", host: "domain.com"
```

request https://domain.com/dev/symfony_app

```
2013/06/23 11:25:37 [error] 22549#0: *668
FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while 
reading response header from upstream, client: *, server: domain.com,
request: "GET /dev/symfony_app HTTP/1.1", upstream: 
"fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock:", host: "domain.com"
```

request https://domain.com/dev/symfony_app/app_dev.php

```
2013/06/23 11:27:06 [error] 22549#0: *797 
FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while 
reading response header from upstream, client: *, server: domain.com, 
request: "GET /dev/symfony_app/app_dev.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: 
"fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock:", host: "domain.com"
```

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/418983/nginx-fastcgi-primary-script-unknown-when-configuring-userdir

Answer (score 1):

Well, what are the dots doing there in your path? You can’t have a directory with three dots as name (at least this would be new to me). The error message from nginx is very specific in that regard. That path doesn’t exist.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;
    root /home/public_html/web;

    location / {
        location ~* ^/dev/symfony_app/(app|app_dev|config)\.php$ {
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
        }
    }
}
```

That should do the trick.

The absolute local path to the index file of your Symfony installation has to be `/home/public_html/web/dev/symfony_app/index.php`. A request to `http://example.com/dev/symfony_app` will map the above location.

I hope this helps, otherwise please leave a comment and describe what else is going wrong.

Comment: dots in my path is just removed username. perhaps I should set there some name to make it clear. I will check proposed solution in few hours and let know if it worked at all.