# NGINX + php-fpm + Symfony 1.4 = :(

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, symfony-1.4, php, vhosts

Ugh, been trying to get NGINX/php-fpm to play nicely with SF 1.4 for a few days now, and can't quite seem to nail down the proper config. I followed the [nginx symfony guide](http://wiki.nginx.org/Symfony) as well as this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3998856/nginx-friendly-php-framework/6750433#6750433), but neither helped, and I suspect it may be because they were being configured against older versions of NGINX (I am working with 1.6.2).

Here is my config:

```
server {

    listen 51000;

    server_name example.mpurcell.dev.example.com;
    access_log /tmp/access.log;
    error_log /tmp/error.log notice;
    root /home/mpurcell/projects/j1n/app/example/current/code/web/;

    index index.php;

    location ~ ^/(app|app_dev)(/|$) {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
    }

    location ~ ^/(app|app_dev).php(/|$) {

        try_files $uri =404;

        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;

        if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
                return 404;
        }

        fastcgi_param SERVICE_ENV 'dev';
        fastcgi_param HTTPS off;

        # http://wiki.nginx.org/Symfony
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;

        fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

And the various responses:

```
$ -> curl -v 10.0.0.7:51000

# Expected
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Server: nginx/1.6.2
< Date: Wed, 01 Oct 2014 23:34:10 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Location: /app

$ -> curl -v 10.0.0.7:51000/app.php

# Expected
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.6.2
< Date: Wed, 01 Oct 2014 23:37:48 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Cache-Control: private

$ -> curl -v 10.0.0.7:51000/app

# Not expected, the script executes but SF throws a 404 with the following error
#  Empty module and/or action after parsing the URL "/app" (/).
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Server: nginx/1.6.2
< Date: Wed, 01 Oct 2014 23:39:09 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Cache-Control: private
```

And it sure looks like the rewrite rule from the vhost config is working:

```
2014/10/01 23:40:30 [notice] 9668#0: *13 "^(.*)$" matches "/app", client: 10.0.0.3, server: example.mpurcell.dev.example.com, request: "GET /app HTTP/1.1", host: "dev-a-2:51000"
2014/10/01 23:40:30 [notice] 9668#0: *13 rewritten data: "/app.php", args: "", client: 10.0.0.3, server: example.mpurcell.dev.example.com, request: "GET /app HTTP/1.1", host: "dev-a-2:51000"
```

And for the sake of completness, the `cgi.fix_pathinfo` is default (=1), and I don't really want to set this to 0.

Also, I should note that `relative_url_root` for the app controller is set to empty string, as it is located in the root web directory.

Stack:

```
nginx 1.6.2
php-fpm 5.4.33
php 5.4.33
```

Comment: Check that your configuration is for the correct version of the framework: if you are using sf 1.4 you post the configuration for sf 2.x (app*.php is tipical of sf2.x and frontend*.php backendé.php is tipical of sf1.4). hope this help.

Comment: The links I posted were to SF2, but in the same link there was reference to a 1.4 NGINX config, which I attempted to use but didn't work either. For my SF1 project I am using app, admin, api controllers instead of the lame fe and be controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally got Symfony and php-fpm to play nicely with each other, and one big piece of that puzzle was to swap out apache for nginx. IMO, the rewrite syntax for nginx > apache. So here is an example of my current app server config:

```
location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php/$1 last;
}

location /admin {
    rewrite ^/admin/(.*)$ /admin/index.php/$1 last;
}

location /app {
    rewrite ^/app/(.*)$ /index.php/$1 last;
}

location ~ index\.php {
    ...
}
```

I did have to create sub dirs for each controller in the web dir, like this:

```
/web
    index.php
    app.php
    admin.php

/web
    /app/index.php
    /admin/index.php
```

I've had this config in prod now for about 2 months with 0 issues, so hopefully this helps other old school symfonians as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that you've not told nginx where Symfony is. I've put an example of nginx configuration that I'm using currently that works.

```
server {
  listen 80;

  server_name example.com;
  chunked_transfer_encoding on;
  proxy_buffering off;

  charset utf-8;

  root /home/mpurcell/projects/j1n/app/example/current/code/web;
  access_log /tmp/access_log;
  error_log /tmp/error_log;

  location /sf/ {
    expires max;
    root /home/mpurcell/projects/j1n/app/example/current/code/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/;
  }

  location ~ ^/(index|frontend_dev|backend_dev)\.php($|/) {
     set  $script $uri;
     set  $path_info "";

     if ($uri ~ "^(.+\.php)(/.*)") {
        set  $script     $1;
        set  $path_info  $2;
   }

   include fastcgi_params;
   fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO         $path_info;
   fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$script;
   fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME       $script;
   fastcgi_param  HTTPS off;
   fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
   fastcgi_keep_conn on;
   fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
 }

 location / {
   if (-f $request_filename) {
     expires max;
     add_header Pragma public;
     add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
     break;
   }
   if ($request_filename ~ ".(js|htc|ico|gif|jpg|png|css)$") {
     expires max;
     add_header Pragma public;
     add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
     break;
   }
   index index.php;
   try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
  }
}
```

For you problem I think the key is this:

```
  location /sf/ {
    expires max;
    root /home/mpurcell/projects/j1n/app/example/current/code/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the config I'm using for symfony 1.4

```
location ~ \.php($|/) {
        fastcgi_pass php56:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
```